# In my Rails app, how can I add two objects to my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

That title probably doesn't sound right, but forgive me, I'm learning Rails for the first time after ten years of windows development.  Currently, I have a model named Drill that should contain two exercises.  To accomplish this based on my current knowledge of Rails, I created a has_many association between the Drill and Exercise models...

```
class Drill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercises, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

But I don't want an open ended list of exercises, instead I'd like to have two references to a single Exercise object, one called left_drill and the other called right_drill.  Based on the documentation, I've changed the code to this...

```
class Drill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :right_drill, :class => :exercise
  has_one  :left_drill, :class => :exercise
end
```

But I don't know if that's right and I'm having a hard time testing it because I don't know how to adjust the Exercise model respectively.  As of now, the Exercise model remains the same...

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drill
end
```

Having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this and, while I continue to read through the docs, I was hoping someone could give me a little direction.

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is correct, though typically the explicit class name is given as a string like so:

```
class Drill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :left_drill, :class => "Exercise"
  has_one :right_drill, :class => "Exercise"
end
```

You can also easily access both drill objects like so, where `my_drill` is an instance of `Drill`:

```
my_drill.left_drill
my_drill.right_drill
```

You may wish to consider renaming them `left_exercise` and `right_exercise` to better reflect that they are an instance of the `Exercise` model, not the `Drill` model.